# Drupal 7 node_save() only title is being saved

Tags: drupal-7, nodes

I am having problems saving a node of a OG content type though I suspect that it is an OG Content type is NOT the reason I am having issues.

I have created a OG Content type called Client Account, the fields are all set and the client does not want to use the standard Drupal UI as it is too busy and it can cause much confusion, I kind of agree, its better to create a form and take the values that make the group and leave all the default stuff out, that way the client just sees a single form.

So I am at this stage, the node appears to be saved when submitted, when I view the newly created content in admin/content the new node is there with its correct title, what is NOT there however is the rest of the group values, al the text boxes that were supposd to have been filled in have not been and the node still is not a node as no other field data has been saved.

Secondly how can I set the language type to english? I tried changing 'und' to 'en' but it still shows as Undefined()

here is my code:

```
    global $user;
    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'client_account';
    $node->title = $form_state['values']['groupName'];
    $node->uid = $user->uid;
    $node->name = $user->name;
    $node->comment = 0;
    $node->promote = 0;
    $node->group_group['und'][0]['value'] = 1; //this is a checkbox value on or off
    /*
     * The rest of the fields in the content type are actually text fields
     */
    $node->og_menu = 1;
    $node->field_company_contact['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['contactName'];
    $node->field_client_email['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['clientEmail'];
    $node->body = 'set body with page values';
    //not implimented yet but requires a default value
    $node->field_logo['und'][0]['value'] = "/images/logo.png";
    $node->field_website['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['website'];
    $node->field_address_line_1['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['addressLine1'];
    $node->field_address_line_2['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['addressLine2'];
    $node->field_address_line_2['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['addressLine3'];
    $node->field_region['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['county'];
    $node->field_region['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['region'];
    $node->field_post_code['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['postCode'];
    //Organic groups fields
    $node->og_description = 'A group managed by ' . $user->name;
    $node->og_register = 0;
    $node->og_directory = 1;
    $node->og_private = 1;
    $node->og_selective = 3;
    //create the node
    $node_save = node_submit($node);
    $result = node_save($node_save);
    drupal_goto("accounts");
```

I have displayed the result of $node_save and $result, $node_save is populated but $result is not, is this normal?

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated

Many Thanks

Jim

Comment: why not use css and hook_form_alter() to make the default node form look better? that way it will definitely work.

Comment: For the second issue, please check this thread. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126484/explain-fields-language-opposed-to-node-language

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed to get the second issue sorted, but as for the first, I think I can sum up the entire argument as to why I am not using hook_form_alter() into two small but extremely powerful words: Clients Wishes

Comment: I feel you, I had lots of weird clients. You can also try `field_attach_form()` to add entity fields to a custom form. Also you can use the `"#access"` property to hide unnecessary form elements. That way you can hide what the client doesn't want to have displayed.

Comment: Thanks for everyones help, I managed to get it sorted, the biggest stumbler was becasue ['und'] should have been [LANGUAGE_NONE] when I changed that it worked

Answer (score 1):

`node_save` does not return a value. However `$node_save` is passed by reference so check to see if `$node_save->nid` is filled to see if it saved successfully.

Comment: Thanks, i wasnt sure but its nice to have clarification